# How do I reverse the lines of 2D array?

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array

How can I reverse the lines of a 2D array, 
like for example:

```
[~][@][@][@]
[~][~][@][~]
[~][~][@][~]
[~][~][~][~]
```

To this:

```
[~][~][~][~]
[~][~][@][~]
[~][~][@][~]
[~][@][@][@]
```

I tried to find but I could not find the algorithm for this kind of task, Help please.

Comment: Can you change your example to use letters instead of number please. Since there are repeating munger it confusing me.

Comment: @StackFlowed I changed my question

Comment: Doesn't matter can you use different elements like 1,2,3 and 4 are there twice which makes it difficult to understand.

Comment: @StackFlowed ok, I changed it

Comment: The initial version of your question was closer to a good question for this site. Generally you must show your attempt to solve your problem and what was the error. Now you just ask for the final solution without showing any effort

Comment: ok I got it thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your 2D array is defined like this :

```
int[][] matrix = new int[nRows][nCols];
```

You can try this :

```
for (int i = 0, k = nRows - 1; i < nRows / 2; i++, k--) {
    int[] temp = matrix[k];
    matrix[k] = matrix[i];
    matrix[i] = temp;
}
```

It will iterate halfway through the rows and swap the first with the ultimate, the second with the penultimate and so forth.

Comment: I changed my question

Answer (score 1):

Try out the below,

```
        List<List<String>> newListOfList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=listOfList.size()-1; i>=0;i--) { //listOfList is the original list
            newListOfList.add(listOfList.get(i));
        }
```